# Angular post call from localhost is failing with api which is protected by cloudflare ssl

Tags: angular, ssl, cloudflare

I am trying to make a post/get api call to the backend server (which i have control of) and is allowing localhost:4200 both http and https but i am getting CORS error. My backend api is protected by Cloudflare with strict SSL and HSTS enabled which I need it enabled at all times. I have generated a self signed certificate and can launch angular in ssl mode with the generated cert and key but I am still getting CORS error, because Cloudflare is blocking it since it is not CA authorized. Any idea, how i can go around it.

Thank you in advance